# Azure Blob Authorization Header | HMAC-SHA256 | OpenSSL, cURL vs Java | Signature Mismatch

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I've been testing consumption of various Azure Blob web services (List, Get, Put, Delete). My tests using cURL on a shell script succeeds. However, my attempt to mimic this functionality on Java does not work. To be precise, the signature value generated on Java does not match with that of OpenSSL's.

Here is the script, *that works well*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# List the blobs in an Azure storage container.

echo "usage: ${0##*/} <storage-account-name> <container-name> <access-key>"

storage_account="ABC"
container_name="XYZ"
access_key="abc=="

blob_store_url="blob.core.windows.net"
authorization="SharedKey"

request_method="GET"
request_date=$(TZ=GMT date "+%a, %d %h %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
storage_service_version="2015-02-21"

# HTTP Request headers
x_ms_date_h="x-ms-date:$request_date"
x_ms_version_h="x-ms-version:$storage_service_version"

# Build the signature string
canonicalized_headers="${x_ms_date_h}\n${x_ms_version_h}"
canonicalized_resource="/${storage_account}/${container_name}"

string_to_sign="${request_method}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n${canonicalized_headers}\n${canonicalized_resource}\ncomp:list\nrestype:container"

# Decode the Base64 encoded access key, convert to Hex.
decoded_hex_key="$(printf $access_key | base64 -d -w0 | xxd -p -c256)"

# Create the HMAC signature for the Authorization header
signature=$(printf "$string_to_sign" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:$decoded_hex_key" -binary |  base64 -w0)

authorization_header="Authorization: $authorization $storage_account:$signature"
# -v or --trace to enable tracing
curl -v \
  -H "$x_ms_date_h" \
  -H "$x_ms_version_h" \
  -H "$authorization_header" \
  "https://${storage_account}.${blob_store_url}/${container_name}?restype=container&comp=list" -o Azure_ListBlob_Output.dat
```

Here is the Java function, that produces an output that mismatches with that of the former:

```
public static String computeHMac256(final String base64Key, final String stringToSign) {
         
//Signature=Base64(HMAC-SHA256(UTF8(StringToSign), Base64.decode(<your_azure_storage_account_shared_key>)))  

            try {
                
                byte[] key = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Key);
                Mac hmacSHA256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
                hmacSHA256.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA256"));
                byte[] utf8Bytes = stringToSign.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                byte[] output = hmacSHA256.doFinal(utf8Bytes);
                return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(output);              
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return null;
}
```

Here is the *stringToSign* value, fed to Java function:

```
"GET\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "\\n" + 
 "x-ms-date:Tue, 30 Mar 2021 10:19:17 GMT\\n" + 
 "x-ms-version:2015-02-21\\n" + 
 "/ABC/XYZ\\n" + 
 "comp:list\\n" + 
 "restype:container";
```

Azure reports the following, when the signature generated by Java is passed on the requested:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

Is anything incorrect with the java function, which was grabbed from [HERE](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/8f086a8d5d24ed5da38dd098dafc63f35ffdb43c/sdk/storage/azure-storage-common/src/main/java/com/azure/storage/common/implementation/StorageImplUtils.java#L201)? Please assist.

Comment: If you see response details, you can see the actual value used by Azure Storage Service to compute the signature. Compare that with your stringToSign and you should find the issue.

Comment: @GauravMantri, Please note that, I am using Java only to compute the hash value. The stringToSign value fed to Java is exactly the same as in shell script. I then use the generated signature in the shell script above, with hardcoded x-ms-date, that returns failure. The shell scripts works well when the signature used is not from Java.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your Java code?

Comment: @GauravMantri, This problem is fixed. Please see my answer, posted below. Thanks for your help thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction to the following value of variable *stringToSign*, fixed the problem:

```
"GET\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "\n" + 
 "x-ms-date:Tue, 30 Mar 2021 10:19:17 GMT\n" + 
 "x-ms-version:2015-02-21\n" + 
 "/ABC/XYZ\n" + 
 "comp:list\n" + 
 "restype:container
```

*Note the changed newline character from \\n to \n.*

Now, the signature value matches. Thanks to @GauravMantri for lending a hand.